# How to control a RF transmitter using Raspberry pi GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, radio

I'm very new to this so apologies if this is a stupid question. But I'm thinking of controlling an RC car with a RF transmitter/ receiver pair using the Raspberry Pi. I'm thinking of hooking up the transmitter on to the GPIO so that I can send commands directly to the transmitter (using python) and then having the receiver on the car itself. Is this possible? What do i need to look for? I've found a pair of RF transmitter/ receiver on ebay but they seem to be for Arduino. Do these work with the raspberry pi or not? 
Again apologies if this is a stupid question. Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you send messages to a receiver on the car.  What is going to process the messages on the car and turn them into movements?

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing which *may* be an interesting learning experience for you but comes with a high risk of failure.

RF communication requires fairly fine grained timing, usually (as with bluetooth, wifi, etc.) via hardware dedicated to that purpose.  The cheap plain jane 433 Mhz things you can get for a few bucks online are interesting in that they don't have that.

You presumably have the additional complication of having to reverse engineer the protocol used by the car. Hopefully you have a controller that works to help you with that. In my experience, just getting a receiver to receive messages via a protocol of your own invention can be tricky. Trying to pick out and properly interpret an unknown pattern is going to be like trying to play scrabble underwater, in a muddy, murky swamp, at night.

There's also the possibility, since the pi is not ideally suited to this, that the timings required are not feasible.

Comment: ++ for the post, but specifically the scrabble analogy

Comment: I see. Well then perhaps I can use an arduino instead (one for the transmitter and one for the receiver) and code the protocol in software? To my knowledge (which really isn't much), something like this seems a lot easier on an Arduino than a raspberry pi. So, I can code the transmitter to send a specific message (probably a string of sorts) and code the receiver to do something specific (like power the right motor or the left motor, I can use a separate motor driver if need be) for specific strings received? Is this feasible?

Comment: I think it is probably easier on an Arduino -- but that's the *only* place I've tried it.  If the timing does not require millisecond level precision (which it need not), then it will be much the same on the Pi but still likely more prone to error.  If it requires faster timing, I don't think doing it in userspace on a multi-tasking OS (i.e., the Pi) will be feasible (but I'm a bit cynical that way).  What I was trying to imply was, go ahead and order some radios, they're so cheap it is irrelevant, and you *may* find it interesting.  But I would bet against success ;P

Comment: To put some perspective on my experience: I did not use a library with the Arduino, I just came up with something vaguely akin to Manchester encoding (you'll find out about that), and I could correctly transmit a 32-bit number about 20-30' through walls.  Using an existing library may simplify things, particularly reverse engineering the protocol.  But to get anywhere close to that distance I had to use antennae (about 1" copper coils, you can buy these for specific frequencies online) *and* power the transmitter with 10-12 V (the rx/tx logic level being independent of the power).